# What wrong with url_for argument?

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I wrote class that descibes adding new users.
But, when I added a new user, I should go to the same view, unfortunately I get Error: `werkzeug.routing.BuildError: ('register_view', {}, None)`

```
class AddUser(BaseView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        return g.user.is_authenticated()
    @expose('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
    def register_view(self):
        if not g.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect(url_for('.login_view'))
        form = RegForm()
        if helpers.validate_form_on_submit(form):
            if db_session.query(User).filter_by(name=form.name.data).count() > 0:
                flash (' A user with this name already exist')
                return redirect(url_for('register_view'))
            if db_session.query(User).filter_by(email=form.email.data).count() > 0:
                flash (' A user with this email already exist')
                return redirect(url_for('register_view'))
            u = User(form.name.data, form.email.data, hashlib.md5(form.password.data.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
            db_session.add(u)
            db_session.commit()
            flash('User has ben added - ' + str(form.name.data))
            return redirect(url_for('register_view'))
        self._template_args['form'] = form
        return self.render('admin/register.html')
```

Comment: Do you have an actual view called `.login_view`? With the `.`?

Comment: I understood. I have 'login_view' in other class 'AdminView'. I did 'AdminView.login_view' and '.register_view' - this work. Thanks for the hint